# If $f\in C^{1}(0,1]\cap C[0,1]$ and $f'\not\in L^{1}(0,1)$, then $f$ oscillates at $0$?

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Please think it easy because it is not an assignment.

> **Question** : Let $f\in C^{1}(0,1]\cap C[0,1]$ and $f'\not\in L^{1}(0,1)$. Then, does $f$ oscillate frequently and $f'$ is unbounded at $0$?

When I asked [the similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1445977/example-of-a-function-s-t-f-in-c1-and-f-notin-l1) before,  Daniel Fischer taught me that such functions satisfy the above conditions.
I accepted at the time but a abstract proof seems to be difficult after thoughts.
Of course, it is clear that such function is Riemann integrable by the fundamental theorem of calculus and $f'$ should be unbounded at $0$.
The problem is whether $f$ should oscillate at $0$ when thinking in the framework of Lebesgue integral.
I think that an image is what the infinite sum of slope diverges due to oscillation but I don't know well how it can prove.

I'm glad if you give me the strategy of proof when you can prove.
It's good even only hints.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If $f'$ was bounded near $0$, then since $f'$ is continuous on $(0,1]$, then
it would follow that $f'$ is bounded on $[0,1]$ and hence integrable.

Since $\int_x^1 f' = f(1)-f(x)$ for $x>0$, we see that $\lim_{x \downarrow 0} \int_x^1 f'$ exists, hence $f'$ must change sign 'frequently' near zero (if $f'$ does not change sign on $(0,\epsilon)$, then it would be integrable).

The description 'oscillates frequently' is a bit vague. However $f$ cannot
be monotone on any interval $[0,\epsilon)$, otherwise $f'$ would not change
sign (near zero) and would be integrable.

Comment: Thank you for giving answer. I don't understand from hence in the second sentence. Why does $f'$ have to change sign? Could you explain more bit detail?

Comment: If $f'$ doesn't change sign on $(0,\epsilon]$, then suppose it is positive. Then $\int_0^\epsilon |f'| = \int_0^\epsilon f'  $ is finite and hence $f'$ is integrable. Similarly for negative.

Comment: I'm afraid that $\int_{0}^{\varepsilon}f'$ can be infinite due to the unbounded of $f'$ at $0$ even if $f'$ does not change sign.

Comment: It can't. Fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I understand. You mean that $\int_{0}^{\varepsilon}|f'|=\int_{0}^{\varepsilon}(f')^{+}-(f')^{-}\to\infty$ if $f'$ changes sign, right?

Comment: No, I am saying that $f(\epsilon)-f(0) = \lim_{x \downarrow 0} \int_x^\epsilon f'$, hence $\int_0^\epsilon f'$ exists in a conditional sense. You know that $\int_0^\epsilon |f'| = \infty$ by hypothesis (otherwise $f'$ would be integrable).

Comment: Sorry, I'm mistaken the order. I understood that $\int_{0}^{\varepsilon}f'$ exists. What I wanted to say is that $f\not\in L^{1}(0,1)$, i.e., the divergence of the sum of $(f')^{+}$ and $(f')^{-}$ is given by change of sign of $f'$. Is it such a thing?

Comment: You lost me there. You are given that $f \in L^1$. Anyway, I am going to sleep. Goodnight.